# invoking remote java process via ssh command

Tags: ssh, invalid-argument

It works like charm form solaris to linux(RHEL5) but gives error when executing from **RHEL5 to RHEL5**

apache log error:

**tcgetattr: Invalid argument
Connection to server20 closed.**

it also gives this error in message log:

> **Jan 20 02:13:39 sj1glm013 kernel: type=1400 audit(1327054419.954:18549): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=18469 comm="sun.sh" path="/web/cgi-bin/remote" 
>   (sun.sh is local script that cgi invokes)**

I am invoking a local shell script from CGI web interface, and that shell script executes another program (script) on remote host.

code of shell script:

```
### it takes parameters form cgi script.
#!/bin/bash
host="$1"
str3="$2"
ssh -t -t -l user $host $str3
exit 0
```

any inputs..

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem, I just took out the `-tt` and that solved it.